# How to post a selected image to firebase storage using Angular cli

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-cli, firebase-storage

i'm trying to make a form which allows user to select an image then post it to firebase storage, but somehow this did not work without any errors. The main problem lies in the addListing function in firebase.service.ts, but no errors showed up, so I could not know what kinds of problem was. When I used a simpler function like this:

```
addListing(listing: Listing){
    let database = firebase.database().ref('listings');
    return database.push(listing);
}
```

It worked, but only for input text data, the selected image was impossible to upload to my firebase storage.

Here are the actual codes:

firebase.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {
  listings: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  listing: FirebaseObjectObservable<Listing>;
  folder: any;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.folder = 'listingimages';
  }

  getListings(){
    this.listings = this.db.list('/listings') as FirebaseListObservable<Listing[]>;
    return this.listings;
  }

  getListingDetails(id){
    this.listing = this.db.object('/listings/' + id) as FirebaseObjectObservable<Listing>;
    return this.listing;
  }


  addListing(listing: Listing){
    // Create root ref
    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    for(let selectedFile of [(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('image')).files[0]]){
      let path = `/${this.folder}/${selectedFile.name}`;
      let iRef = storageRef.child(path);
      iRef.put(selectedFile).then((snapshot) => {
        listing.image = selectedFile.name;
        listing.path = path;
        return this.listings.push(listing);
      });
    }
  }  
}

interface Listing{
  $key?: string;
  title?: string;
  type?: string;
  image?: string;
  city?: string;
  owner?: string;
  bedroom?: string;
  path?: string;
}
```

add-listing.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseService } from '../../services/firebase.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-listing',
  templateUrl: './add-listing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-listing.component.css']
})
export class AddListingComponent implements OnInit {
  title: any;
  owner: any;
  city: any;
  bedrooms: any;
  price: any;
  type: any;
  image: any;

  constructor(
    private firebaseService: FirebaseService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onAddSubmit(){
    let listing = {
      title: this.title,
      city: this.city,
      owner: this.owner,
      bedrooms: this.bedrooms,
      price: this.price,
      type: this.type
    }

    this.firebaseService.addListing(listing);

    this.router.navigate(['listings']);
    console.log(listing);
  }
}
```

Here is the view:

```
<form (submit)="onAddSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" name="title" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>City</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="city" name="city" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Owner</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="owner" name="owner" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Bedrooms</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="number" [(ngModel)]="bedrooms" name="bedrooms" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Type</label>
    <select class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="type" name="type" required>
      <option value="Estate">Estate</option>
      <option value="Condo">Condo</option>
      <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="image" name="image" [(ngModel)]="image" type="file" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Price</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="price" name="price" required>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your firebase.service.ts you are importing firebase utility like this:
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'; *this is currently not available* to import all utilities import without the /app like this

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Then change this line in your export class: `listing:FirebaseObjectObservable<Listing>;` TO `listing:FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;`

In your addListing function pass in the *listing* parameter from the onAddSubmit function in add-Listing component not *listing:Listing* it should be like this:

```
addListing(listing){
     // Create root ref
    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    for(let selectedFile of [(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('image')).files[0]]){
      let path = `/${this.folder}/${selectedFile.name}`;
      let iRef = storageRef.child(path);
      iRef.put(selectedFile).then((snapshot) => {
        listing.image = selectedFile.name;
        listing.path = path;
        return this.listings.push(listing);
      });
    }
  }
```

make sure you add firebase to the environment i add on both for production and developement then import environment in your app.module.ts angularFire has good documentation on how to set up here the link: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md.
Wish you Luck..